# Error :- socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed in get request

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, python-requests, python-sockets

```
import socket
mysocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysocket.connect(("http://www.py4inf.com",80))
c="http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n".encode()
mysocket.send(c)

while True:
    data=mysocket.recv(512)
    if len(data) <1:
        break
    else:
        print(data.decode())
mysocket.close()

Error:-
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Python_practice_file\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    mysocket.connect(("http://www.py4inf.com",80))
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

I am getting this error while I am learning web socket programming in python but it seems like I am getting an error if anyone can solve this problem I'll be very grateful. I saw some answers but they are not related because i am not using proxy,

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `http://` part.

This indicates protocol, which is not part of the FQDN `getaddrinfo()` tries to resolve.

---

Also change

`c="http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"`

to

`c="GET /code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"`

But I suggest using [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) or [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io) libraries if you want to do HTTP requests.